# Wrong alignment in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How can I set Text alignment in a canvas ?
My text is center now.
But when I increase or decrease the texts, I'll get wrong alignment.

My Code is:

```
<canvas id="puzzle" width="480" height="480"></canvas>
```

```
var plugin = {};
var boardSize = document.getElementById('#canvasid').width;
plugin.context:  document.getElementById('#canvasid').getContext('2d');
```

```
plugin.context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255, 0.5)';
plugin.context.fillRect(0, 0,boardSize , boardSize);
plugin.context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0, 1)';
plugin.context.font = "30px Arial";
plugin.context.fillText('my text goes here' , boardSize/4, boardSize/2);
```

Full code is here:
https://github.com/amirhossein693/puzzle

Comment: please can you provide a http://www.sscce.org/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use `textAlign` to horizontally align text to an "X" centerpoint:**

```
context.textAlign='center';

context.fillText('This text will be horizontally centered at x=150', 150,50);
```

**Use `textBaseline` to vertically align text to a "Y" midpoint:**

```
context.textBaseline='middle';

context.fillText('This text will be vertically centered at y=50', 150,50);
```